# I am confused on how to properly code the while loop. How to make sure it iterates through all the values in the array

Tags: java

The output should be that the array is sorted into descending order but my code stops after one iteration and doesn't fully sort the entire array and I don't know how to fix it. I am a beginner to please explain the logic in simple terms

```
 public static int[] insertionSort(int[] array){
    for(int i1 = 1; i1 < array.length; i1++){
        int indexCurrent = i1;
        boolean done = false;
        while(indexCurrent <= (array.length -1) && done == false){
            if(array[indexCurrent] > array[indexCurrent-1]){
                int temp = array[indexCurrent-1];
                array[indexCurrent-1] = array[indexCurrent];
                array[indexCurrent] = temp;
                indexCurrent++;
            }else{
                done = true;
            }
           
        }

    }
```

return array;
}

Comment: Compare your code with [the Java code on this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be decrementing `indexCurrent`.

```
while(indexCurrent > 0 && !done){
    if(array[indexCurrent] > array[indexCurrent-1]){
        int temp = array[indexCurrent-1];
        array[indexCurrent-1] = array[indexCurrent];
        array[indexCurrent] = temp;
        indexCurrent--;
    }else{
        done = true;
    }
}
```